# PHP SOAP Client is not working

Tags: php, soap, client

I never developed a SOAP client, and now I have to do it and am having difficulties. This are the input parameters I have to send to the method "Agregar":

```
<Clientes>
    <Cliente>
        <Rut>123456785</Rut>
        <Nombre>123456785</Nombre>
    </Cliente>
</Clientes>
```

this is the testing code for the client I have done yet:

```
<?php
class Socio {
    function Socio($rut, $nombre) 
    {
        $this->nombre = $nombre;
        $this->rut = $rut;
    }
}

$client = new SoapClient("theurl...");

$socio = new Socio(156371777, "Sebastian");

$params = array(
  "Cliente" => $socio,
);

$response = $client->__soapCall("Agregar", $params);

var_dump($response);
```

but it is not working... I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Server] The server can't process the request. ---> The value cannot be null. Parameter name: s in /var/www/friends/awto/intouch/ccinterface.php:22 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/friends/awto/intouch/ccinterface.php(22): SoapClient->__soapCall('Agregar', Array) #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/friends/awto/intouch/ccinterface.php on line 22

Comment: Soap client has some methods for debugging. You need to check what you are really sending.You have to enable tracking in soapclient constructor. Seems that presented error is coming from server, so probably you are sending empty message or something like that http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php#112970

Comment: ok I added the 'trace' option, but I see the same result. The problem is, I don't have access to the server. I only have the specs. But my question is: how would you create a client for the specified input parameters? I am doing something wrong?

Comment: What does it mean that you don't have access to the server? You have a client and params, but you can't send any request to soap server and see if your code works? Do you have just sample request or full WSDL file? If you don't have wsdl, maybe you can ask for it. Then often PHP can do a lot work around mapping and building the xml for you.

Comment: I can make requests to the server... What I mean by I don't have access is that I cannot modify it. 
My simple question is: given the specs of the method "Agregar" that I provided, am I calling that method right?? Or am I doing something wrong (clearly I am, but I don't know what)

Comment: Are you working in WSDL-mode or not? Try to intercept the request which you are sending (trace option + link which I've posted above), and compare that message to one which you think should be sending. If you are using WSDL, then compare your message with requirements from WSDL. It is not possible to figure out what you are doing wrong just by looking at information which you've provided. SoapClient works differently depending on configuration, and sometimes you may experience troubles when integrating with soap server built in different technology than PHP.